# Using group_by with where statement in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, group-by

Already check [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/29-group-by-month) video which is very helpful. But actually i dont just want to group just months. I want to group them with a condition too. So i have;

```
MyModel.where("state = 'A'").all.group_by { |q| q.created_at.beginning_of_month }.count
```

But it gives me all records that states in 'A' not in current month specifically. Am i missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: You fetch all records that have `state = 'A'`, then group them. It produces a hash where keys are beginnings of months and values - arrays of records that where created in the corresponding months. Applying `count` to this give you just a number of different months when records with `state = 'A'` where created. Can you describe better the result you want to get?

Comment: Ah not mentioned count is my bad.for ex. i just want to fetch record count that created in current month which states in 'A'.

Comment: If all you want is to count records with `state = 'A'` created in the current month why do you need grouping? Do you want to get number of records created in every month?

Comment: I used grouping because maybe i can need statistics about every month in future. but can you tell me how i get all records with current month and state condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get records with `state = 'A'` that were created in this month like that:

```
MyModel.where(['state = ? AND ? <= created_at AND created_at <= ?', 
               'A', Date.today.beginning_of_month, Date.today.end_of_month])
```

Applying `count` to that query you'll get number of such records.

If you need number of records per month and you can do it like that (not the most efficient way, though):

```
records = MyModel.where("state = 'A'").all
result = records.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = 0 }) do |record, hash|
  hash[record.created_at.beginning_of_month] += 1
end
```

You might need to have a look how [`Hash#new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-new) works with block and what [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) does.

More efficient way to count records per month would be to use plain SQL to group rows by month and that apply count to that. In that case you won't fetch records itself from the DB that will be faster if you have quite a big table.

Comment: thank you that solves my problem for now. but if i want to get all statistics about record, how will i do it? i think that will be my next question in near future :).

Comment: Added solution for fetching stats per month.